# Dynamically deleting a control does not refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

First I am building the page in question on a legacy site so I am largely stuck with ASP.Net webfomrs.

I have succeeded in getting the button for adding controls to the page to work, and the button to delete controls from the page to half way work.

My click events do fire and the page updates as expected when clicking the add button.

When clicking the delete button, the click event does fire. However, the page does not update to finish removing the button until the user clicks another button.

Here is the code for my delete button click:

```
protected void BtnDeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeleteControls(sender);
}

private void DeleteControls(object sender)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    string id = button.ID;
    int index = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(id, @"\d+$").Value);
    Panel row = (Panel)button.Parent;

    for (int i = row.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (row.Controls[i] is Button)
            ((Button)row.Controls[i]).Click -= new EventHandler(BtnDeleteRow_Click);
        row.Controls[i].Dispose();
    }
    row.Parent.FindControl(row.ID).Dispose();
    if (id.Contains("Leadership"))
        LeadershipControlsIndexes.RemoveAt(LeadershipControlsIndexes.Find(x => x == index));
    else if (id.Contains("Elected"))
        ElectedControlsIndexes.RemoveAt(ElectedControlsIndexes.Find(x => x == index));
}
```

Stepping through my code reveals the following:

- First click of a delete button fires the BtnDeleteRow_Click method
- Second click of the **same** button does not fire BtnDeleteRow_click, but it does cause a new PostBack event the refreshes the page.
- If the second click is on another button, that button's click event is fired and the controls associated with the first button go away on the page refresh caused by this new button click.

For reference, here is the code for my add button click events:

```
protected void BtnAddLeadershipRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateLeadershipControl();
}

private void CreateLeadershipControl()
{
    LeadershipControlsMaxIndex++;
    LeadershipControlsIndexes.Add(LeadershipControlsMaxIndex - 1);
    AddLeadershipControls(LeadershipControlsIndexes[LeadershipControlsIndexes.Count - 1]);
}

private void AddLeadershipControls(int index)
{
    Panel pnlLeadershipControls = new Panel
    {
        ID = "LeadershipControls" + index.ToString(),
        CssClass = "pnlControls"
    };

    Button btnDelete = new Button()
    {
        ID = "btnLeadershipRowDelete" + index.ToString(),
        Text = "-"
    };
    btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(BtnDeleteRow_Click);
    btnDelete.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 1.4em;");
    pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(btnDelete);

    DropDownList ddlRegion = new DropDownList
    {
        DataSource = regions,
        ID = "LeadershipRegion" + index.ToString()
    };
    ddlRegion.DataBind();
    ddlRegion.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 7em;");
    pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(ddlRegion);

    DropDownList ddlProfit = new DropDownList
    {
        DataSource = profit,
        ID = "LeadershipProfit" + index.ToString(),
        CssClass = "ddlProfit"
    };
    ddlProfit.DataBind();
    ddlProfit.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 7.5em;");
    pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(ddlProfit);

    TextBox txtOrg = new TextBox
    {
        ID = "txtLeadershipOrganization" + index.ToString()
    };
    txtOrg.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 20em;");
    pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(txtOrg);

    TextBox txtPos = new TextBox
    {
        ID = "txtLeadershipPosition" + index.ToString()
    };
    txtPos.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 20em;");
    pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(txtPos);

    CheckBox cbCurrent = new CheckBox
    {
        ID = "cbLeadershipCurrent" + index.ToString(),
        Text = "Current?",
    };
    cbCurrent.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; font: 700 1em Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif !important");
    pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(cbCurrent);

    pnlLeadershipFields.Controls.Add(pnlLeadershipControls);
}
```

I guess, that my question is twofold:

1. Why does my add button successfully update the page, but my delete button not do so?
2. What do I do to fix my delete buttons?

Comment: are these controls on a plain asp.net web forms page, or are they inside an update panel, or does the page use any other "ajax" methods to update itself?

Comment: These controls are not part of an UpdatePanel.  I think that it is a fairly basic webform although is built from a series of .Master pages. There is no Ajax involved at this point that I am aware of but there is plenty of JavaScript. I do not think that I am calling any JavaScript but I could be wrong...